# SSL certificate for subdomains and other domains

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm working on a hosted webshop application that allows shop owners to quickly start their own webshop. Initially their shop will be available on a subdomain (shopname.shopperz.pro) but they can also change their nameserver settings and forward any traffic to our servers, so their shop will be available on their own domain name (while still being hosted by us).

We want to use SSL to secure the connection. I know that for the subdomains we can use a wildcard SSL so that all subdomains are covered.

For the domains owned by the shop owners, I would assume the shop owner would have to get the SSL certificate himself. My quetion is: will the wildcard SSL impact the certificates of my clients with their own domains? Is there anything else we need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

1. Get a multidomain certificate, and add all of the customers' domains onto it.  This might be infeasible, as you'd need to deploy a new certificate every time a domain was added or removed.  Some customers might also object to having their domain be one of 20 in a certificate.
2. Host each other domain on a dedicated IP address, and configure the virtual host for that address to use the certificate for that domain.
3. Serve multiple SSL certificates from the same IP address, *if* both your server and client support Server Name Indication (SNI) in SSL.  See the [Apache FAQ](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2) about this.